# Splide slider Vue package simply doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, splidejs

No idea what the issue here is, should be as simple as install, import and use!

I have got a base component, this imports another component which contains Splider:

```html
// Base.vue

<template>
    <div class="detailGallery">
        <div class="detailGalleryViewer">
            <keep-alive>
                <component v-bind:is="currentComponent" :vehicle-id="vehicleId"></component>
            </keep-alive>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        vehicleId: {
            required: true,
            type: Number|String
        }
    },
    computed: {
        currentComponent() {
            return () => { component: import('./Gallery.vue') };
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
// Gallery.vue

<template>
  <div>Gallery</div>
</template>
<script>
import { Splide, SplideSlide } from '@splidejs/vue-splide';
export default {
  components: {
    Splide,
    SplideSlide,
  },
  props: {
    vehicleId: {
      required: true,
      type: Number | String,
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]

As you can see very simple setup, however all i'm getting is the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
> at Module../node_modules/@splidejs/vue-splide/dist/js/vue-splide.esm.js (9b9e393020eef216bce4.js:2463:80)

Anyone encountered this!? Got a deadline and I need to use this!

Comment: check your version in `package.json`, check their github for bug reports, try debugging that exact file in the error message. I have no clue tbh what could be the problem if you are exactly doing as said in the tutorial. It might even be some compiler issue from webpack or whatever you're using.

Comment: Think it was a compiler version, need to do further testing before I post an answer. Thanks